# Prestashop module paymentasiaalipay how to setup confirmation redirect link?

Tags: prestashop

Recently I have added Asia Alipay as my prestashop payment method. But I am stuck on the confirmation page after the customer pays the order and redirects from Alipay to my server. That is because the redirect URL is 404. It is located in prestashop/modules/paymentasiaalipay/controllers/front/confirmation.php.

```
class PaymentasiaalipayConfirmationModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

    public function initContent() 
    {
        $this->setTemplate('module:paymentasiaaliapay/views/templates/front/testing.tpl');
    }
}
```

I try to publicize it by adding it into SEO/url setting, adding a initContent() function with setTemplate() point to a view, then accessing it by normal HTTPS get request, but it still returns 404. It does not ready for prestashop. I want to ask how to setup the external modules controller so that the customer can access it directly?